# Looking up group policy for IE11 indexedDB

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-10, internet-explorer

We have a client that uses our application via IE11. All of our clients are working fine except one. With this client, when they bring up IE11, indexedDB is not available. We quadruple checked compatibility modes (document modes), desktop mode and the usual suspects and they all seem fine.

The only thing I've uncovered that could disable IE11 indexedDB outside of those settings is a group policy setting. This link http://ayvazyan.net/2018/03/group-policies-which-could-affect-your-web-app/ says there's a group policy to enable/disable indexedDB. I can't seem to find a way to verify what the current value is for this setting on my local.

Looking for steps for the client to follow to check that setting themselves.

Comment: If you have this setup in group policy, you can run rsop.msc and see if you see it listed in that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate if the client computer as seted this policy or not please validate the registry.

This specific key to be exact;

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserStorage\IndexedDB\AllowWebsiteDatabases, be sure it's not set to 0.

You can validate if in the Internet Option if DOM storage is Enable or Not. Internet Option, Advanced, Security, Enable DOM Storage.

If the DOM storage is not enabled then it disable directly IndexedDB.

Comment: I'm not seeing the 'BrowserStorage' folder in regedit for Internet Explorer. Is that for a different Windows version (10)?

Comment: @pmilkman It seem not set then, as if a GPO target IndexedDB, it would write the setting there. For testing you can create the registry key and set it to 1.

Comment: Gotcha. That was me testing on my machine, where IndexedDB works fine. I'll play around with that then.

Comment: In Internet option, general, settings, Caches and databases, is the Allow website caches and databases is ticked ?

Comment: @pmilkman oh ok, gotcha. I tell the registry location, as it's in HCU (the user can see and edit there usually). You can reverse the GPO for testing on the computer by changing the key if you see something usually. If set by GPO, it will reset at the GPO interval to the setting pushed

Comment: Thank you, yagmoth555! The Caches and Databases resolved the issue for one of our customers already, we're checking on 2 other customers that have since reported the problem. I'll mark as accepted.